# Is set $S$ complete ? Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $S=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R} : |\cos x|\le \frac{1}{2}\right\}$ .

**My question**: Is  set $S$   complete ? Yes/No

**My attempt** :I think yes

Here $$S=\left\{\frac{2n \pi}{3}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

S  is closed  because  $\mathbb{R}  \setminus S = \left(-\infty ,\frac{2n \pi}{3}\right) \cup \left(\frac{2n \pi}{3}, \infty\right)$ is open.

Comment: First, your $S$ is wrong, and second, $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is also wrong. We have $S = \cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} [n\pi+\pi/3, n\pi+2\pi/3]$.

Comment: okay @Riemann  but  $\cos \frac{2n\pi}{3}=1/2$

Comment: No. $\cos\frac{2\pi}{3} = -\frac{1}{2}$ and I think the equation is irrelavant to your question.

Comment: oh sorry    Actually  , i  was thinking  this $|\cos \frac{2\pi}{3}| =1/2$@Riemann

Comment: Then would you correct your question now?

Comment: Question is correct.I think  you are misunderstanding @Riemann

Comment: The question is correct, but your attempted solution is quite wrong.

Comment: $S$ is a closed subset of a complete space, hence...